# How to convert Dataframe to a transaction data in the Sequence of Transaction group by customer

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that reads as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Invoice': [1, 1, 2, 3,3,3,4,5,5,6],
                    'Stockcode': ['A', 'B', 'C','A','D','E','B','C','A','D' ],
                    'InvoiceDate': ['01-01-2019', '01-01-2019', '14-01-2019', 
                                    '17-02-2019','17-02-2019','17-02-2019',
                    '01-01-2019','14-01-2019','14-01-2019', 
                                    '17-02-2019'],
            'CustomerID':['C1','C1','C1','C1','C1','C1',
                                     'C2','C2','C2','C2' ]})
```

I am looking at an output that show as

```
Customer       Value:
C1             {A,B},{C},{A,D,E}
C2             {B},{C,A},{D}
```

I am pretty new to Python. I tried different group by methods. I dont want to use For loops, as it the dataset is very huge for me.

Comment: you want the { } in the result?

Comment: yes, that will divide the group transactions.

Comment: divide the group transactions ? what is the logic? invoice ?

Answer (score 0):

Reconstruct the transactions back into invoices by grouping on CustomerID and invoice and getting a list of the Stockcodes.

```
 df = df.groupby(['CustomerID','Invoice'])['Stockcode'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Now group the resulting invoices (list of stock codes) into a list.

```
df = df.groupby('CustomerID')['Stockcode'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

What you end up with is a list of lists, where each list is essential an invoice for that customer.

Output

```
  CustomerID                 Stockcode
0         C1  [[A, B], [C], [A, D, E]]
1         C2        [[B], [C, A], [D]]
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['CustomerID', 'InvoiceDate'])['Stockcode'].agg(list).groupby(level=0).agg(list)`

Comment: @user3483203 Yep!  But IDK if he would necessarily grasp that being new but maybe!

Comment: How can one add time diff concept here. So above u group by same date as one itemset. I want to group it one itemset if the datetime is within a range of like 2 days or 2 mins. How do we bring that here? Thanks